# how to rewrite a static URL using htacces

Tags: .htaccess

I'm sure my question is very simple for somebody that knows it, but I cant find any ways on the internet to rewrite a STATIC URL to make it cleaner, for example, I would like to have this:

1st (my link I would like to change)

www.mycoolsite.com/contact.php

To become this :

www.mycoolsite.com/contact

Thanks alot! Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be solved with following rules. Note it also redirects you when you enter the address with suffix.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# exists file with extension?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0.php [L]

# redirect, but only once
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Source: http://phpfashion.com/hadanka-znate-mod_rewrite#comment-7359 (not in English)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Apache you could enabled MultiViews

To enable it you will need to add to your Apache configuration

```
Options +MultiViews
```

If allowoverride has been configured you can add the multiviews to your .htaccess file.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride